# Angular Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm trying to build a nested reactive form with formArray, but i get error: 'Cannot find control with path', it works fine if there is only one item in array, but if there is more that 1 it returns error. what am i doing wrong?

carPartCategories in ngfor is just data i get from server.

```html
    <form [formGroup]="updateEstimation">
      <ng-container formArrayName="carPartStatus">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let i of carPartCategories; let j = index;">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="j">
              <div class="content-desc mt-4 mb-5">
                <div class="row mt-4 parts-row align-items-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <span class="p-2 nusx">
                      {{i.carPartCategory}}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <span class="p-2 nusx">
                      {{i.carPartSubCategory}}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <span class="p-2 nusx">
                      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>choose</mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="status">
                          <mat-option>
                            test
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <span class="p-2 nusx">
                      X{{i.quantity}}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2 price">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="price" class="form-control" formControlName="price">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="comment mt-4 mb-5" *ngIf="i.comment">
                <p class="mtav">comment</p>
                <p class="nusx">{{i.comment}}</p>
              </div>
              <hr>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
       </form>
```

.ts

```js
      this.updateEstimation = this.fb.group({
        carPartStatus: new FormArray([
          new FormGroup({
            status: new FormControl(''),
            price: new FormControl('')
          })
        ])
      });
```

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-material-reactive-form-starter-bc7hd4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Can you post a full example in CodeSandbox or something similar?

Comment: hi thanks for the comment! yes i can https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-material-reactive-form-starter-bc7hd4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because you added only one item under the `FormArray`, and looped through another array `carPartCategories` to render the items.

For each item in the `carPartCategories` array, the `FormArray` of `carPartStatus` should contain an item as a `FormGroup`, and keep the `FormArray` always synced with your original array by adding/removing the controls to it.

You can try something like the following:

```js
// prop represents the `carPartStatus` control
carPartStatusCtrl: FormArray;

//...


this.carPartStatusCtrl = this.createFormArray(carPartCategories);

this.updateEstimation = this.fb.group({
  carPartStatus: this.carPartStatusCtrl,
});

// ...

// Create a `FormArray` from the provided array:
createFormArray(origin: CarPartCategories[]) {
  return new FormArray(
    origin.map(
      (item) =>
        new FormGroup({
          status: new FormControl(item.status),
          price: new FormControl(item.price),
        })
    )
  );
}
```

Each change on the original array should be reflected into the `FormArray`, for example, if you add a new item to the original array, a new item should be added to the `FormArray` like the following:

```js
appendNewItem(item: CarPartCategories): void {
  this.carPartStatusCtrl.push(
    new FormGroup({
      status: new FormControl(item.status),
      price: new FormControl(item.price),
    })
  );
}
```

### Update

Based on your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-material-reactive-form-starter-oysfzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts), you're receiving the original array from the HTTP request, but you initialized the `updateEstimation` form-group without waiting the result to return, so your `FromArray` in this case won't contain any items since the `carPartCategories` is still empty.

To resolve this issue, you have to:

- Either move the `updateEstimation` initialization to be within the `subscribe` function (and DON'T render the template until the updateEstimation is being initialized, by using `*ngIf="updateEstimation"` on the `form` element).
- Or append the new items to the `carPartStatusCtrl` form-array, once the data is received using the `appendNewItem` function I mentioned above in my solution.

Comment: hi! thank you so much for answer. i have one more question, you are code does work fine with simple array i tested, but in my project i have http request and it wont work. i made a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-material-reactive-form-starter-oysfzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I updated my answer to resolve the issue in your `StackBlitz`.

Comment: Hi! thanks again. when  move updateEstimation inside subscribe i get error Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. for the second solution i dont get it, can you explain it please?

Comment: Regarding the second solution, I updated it to be more clear, and the same for the first one. The `*ngIf="updateEstimation"` should be added on `form` element to render the form only once the `updateEstimation` is initialized.